# how to preprocess the data and load into hive

Tags: hadoop, hive, hadoop-streaming

I completed my hadoop course now I want to work on Hadoop. I want to know the workflow from data ingestion to visualize the data.

I am aware of how eco system components work and I have built hadoop cluster with 8 datanodes and 1 namenode:
1 namenode --Resourcemanager,Namenode,secondarynamenode,hive
8 datanodes--datanode,Nodemanager

I want to know the following things:

1. I got data .tar structured files and first 4 lines have got description.how to process this type of data im little bit confused.
   1.a Can I directly process the data as these are tar files.if its yes how to remove the data in the first four lines should I need to untar and remove the first 4 lines
   1.b and I want to process this data using hive.

Please suggest me how to do that.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Can I directly process the data as these are tar files.

Yes, see the below solution.

> if yes, how to remove the data in the first four lines

Starting **Hive v0.13.0**, There is a table property, `tblproperties ("skip.header.line.count"="1")` while creating a table to tell `Hive` the number of rows to ignore. To ignore first four lines - `tblproperties ("skip.header.line.count"="4")`

```
CREATE TABLE raw (line STRING)
   ROW FORMAT DELIMITED FIELDS TERMINATED BY '\t' LINES TERMINATED BY '\n';

CREATE TABLE raw_sequence (line STRING)
   STORED AS SEQUENCEFILE
   tblproperties("skip.header.line.count"="4");

LOAD DATA LOCAL INPATH '/tmp/test.tar' INTO TABLE raw;

SET hive.exec.compress.output=true;
SET io.seqfile.compression.type=BLOCK; -- NONE/RECORD/BLOCK (see below)

INSERT OVERWRITE TABLE raw_sequence SELECT * FROM raw;
```

To view the data:

```
select * from raw_sequence
```

Reference: [Compressed Data Storage](https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/Hive/CompressedStorage)

Answer (score 0):

Follow the below steps to achieve your goal:

1. Copy the data(ie.tar file) to the client system where hadoop is installed.
2. Untar the file and manually remove the description and save it in local.
3. Create the metadata(i.e table) in hive based on the description.
   **Eg**: If the description contains emp_id,emp_no,etc.,then create table in hive using this information and also make note of field separator used in the data file and use the corresponding  field separator in create table query. Assumed that file contains two columns which is separated by comma then below is the syntax to create the table in hive.

   ```
     Create table tablename (emp_id int, emp_no int)
     Row Format Delimited
     Fields Terminated by ','
   ```
4. Since, data is in structured format, you can load the data into hive table using the below command.
   `LOAD DATA LOCAL INPATH '/LOCALFILEPATH' INTO TABLE TABLENAME`.
5. Now, local data will be moved to hdfs and loaded into hive table.
6. Finally, you can query the hive table using `SELECT * FROM TABLENAME;`

Comment: thank you for your quick response.  I have got an idea now.
In my case
file structure: /home/admin/jan/file1 --> file1.tar
file zip has been done on home directory so if I unzip this file the file structured will be created like below,
/home/admin/jan/file1
in the above case will files be read using hive external tables?
Could you please let me know where to install hive either on Namenode or Datanode?
i have configured Datanode and secondarynamenode on the same server while starting the services im seeing secondarynamnode is running on 0.0.0.0..

Comment: Yes, you can create external table, but the data should be in HDFS not in local home directory. So, use hadoop fs -put /home/admin/jan/file1 /hdfs_path command to put the data from local to hdfs and then create the external table on that data using CREATE EXTERNAL TABLE TABLENAME(COL...) LOCATION '/hdfs_path' command.  Also you can install hive in any node in the cluster.

Comment: I have directory structure like below in my hadoop,

/hadoop/maindirec/subdirect1/files1-100    /hadoop/maindirec/subdirect2/files1-100    /hadoop/maindirec/subdirect3/files1-100    /hadoop/maindirec/subdirect4/files1-100    /hadoop/maindirec/subdirect5/files1-100

Now i want to create hive table with orc format as maindirec and subdirect1-5 as partiations